# formatting a text file before mailing it in shell script

Tags: file, shell, email, unix, scripting

Currently i am using

```
uuencode "file" "report.txt" | mailx -s "Subject" xyz@abc.com
```

I am getting output as

```
002506960 830148XXM ILD514CSE 0000000 004129197 737620BQJ LCT453INN 0000000 000130122 984062NOR YUR416XER 0000480 000134266 095151MET RUB648DEA 0000210
000232322 941669CAR DET672KEH 0000600 000232320 941669CAR DET672KEH 0071014 000232325 941669CAR DET672KEH 0071014
```

Required output :

```
032506961 830148XXM ILD514CSE 0000000    
034129191 737620BQJ LCT453INN 0000000    
030130121 984062NOR YUR416XER 0000480    
030134261 095151MET RUB648DEA 0000210    
030232321 941669CAR DET672KEH 0000600    
030232321 941669CAR DET672KEH 0071014    
030232321 941669CAR DET672KEH 0071014
```

(Note : no gap between the lines)
any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe your output to:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i%4==0)?ORS:OFS}'
```

That will give:

```
002506960 830148XXM ILD514CSE 0000000
004129197 737620BQJ LCT453INN 0000000
000130122 984062NOR YUR416XER 0000480
000134266 095151MET RUB648DEA 0000210
000232322 941669CAR DET672KEH 0000600
000232320 941669CAR DET672KEH 0071014
000232325 941669CAR DET672KEH 0071014
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explaint a bit. also how would i save this output in the the file which i have to mail ?

Comment: To save output use: `uuencode "file" "report.txt" | mailx -s "Subject" xyz@abc.com | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i%4==0)?ORS:OFS}' > output` **Explanation:** This awk is inserting `ORS` (newline by default) every time field count is divisible by 4

Comment: Thank you for your response. but it is the same output as before. it is not putting an enter after the fourth column to start a new line.

Comment: You can see the awk output in my answer which I generated from your given output.